# JBoss - User transaction not inited

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

In the following code, a Null pointer exception is raised when I try to call `beginTransaction` method. I thought that JBoss would init my transaction... apparently not :\

What am I missing ?

JBoss 5.1.0.GA
JPA 1
JDK 6

---

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

public abstract class AbstractDAO {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "miniDS")
    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    @Resource
    protected UserTransaction t;

    public AbstractDAO() {

    }

    protected void beginTransaction() throws Throwable {
        t.begin();
    }

    protected void commitTransaction() throws Throwable {
        t.commit();
    }

    protected void rollbackTransaction() throws Throwable {
        t.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Through Spring's transactionManager you could just use the annotations @Transactional on your services which are using your DAOs. 

This would handle the begin/end of your transactions automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AbstractDAO does not seem to be managed. Injection only works in container managed objects. This is not specific to injection of UserTransaction, but injection in general. As result *emf* is null as well. Java EE specification lists following classes to be able to use injection:

- Servlet: servlets, servlet filters, event listeners
- JSP: tag handlers, tag library event listeners
- JSF: scoped managed beans
- JAX-WS: service endpoints, handlers
- EJB: beans, interceptors
- Managed Beans: managed beans
- CDI: CDI-style managed beans, decorators
- Java EE Platform: main class (static), login callback handler

Possible workaround are to move injection of resources to managed class or use JNDI lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Your concrete class ConcreteDAO which extends AbstractDAO, should be an ejb, as said by Mikko Maunu and should manage itself transaction (beans that manage transaction themselves BMT), in other words:

```
    @Stateless
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
    public class ConcreteDAO extends AbstractDAO {

    ...

    }
```

And it be better if you inject EntityManager in your AbstractDAO, and configure JBOSS datasource to manage transaction (local-tx-datasource or xa-datasource).
you can look at JBOSS DS config at:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources

if you want to manage transaction yourself through EntityManager, with entityManagerFactory

```
  EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

you can't use UserTransaction and the JBoss DS should be no-tx-datasource

Answer (score 2):

If you inject your persistence unit, try to get the transaction through the EntityManager.

```
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

For more information, have a look here: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/How-to-use-@PersistenceUnit-annotation